# Setting div's height in percentages

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to resize *flex-container* by using *percentage units* like `height: 10%`, but it only fits to *content's* `height`. If i try using `px`, it works, but i definitely need *percentages*.

```css
.top_section {
  display: flex;
  height: 10%;
  background-color: #8ac858;
}
```

```html
<div class="top_section">
  <div class="nav menu">
    <a href="#" class="nav_unit">Home</a>
    <a href="#" class="nav_unit">Rating</a>
    <a href="#" class="nav_unit">Map</a>
  </div>
  <div class="auth_menu">
    <a href="#" class="auth_text">Register</a>
    <a href="#" class="auth_text">Login</a>
    <input type="text" class="login">
    <input type="password" class="password">
  </div>
</div>
```

What should i do in this case?

Comment: `.top_section` has `height: 10%`. So `.top_section`'s height will be `10%` of its parent. So then you need to set the height of its parent element. This is really not related to flexbox

Comment: @vmoh_ir parent element is <body>

Comment: So then you can have `body: { height: 100vh; }`

Answer (score 1):

`.top_section` has `height: 10%`. So `.top_section`'s height will be `10%` of its parent. So then you need to set the height of its parent element.

For example, if its parent is `body`, then you can have

```
body: {
    height: 100vh;
}
```